# Windows 8 ListView SelectedIndex / SelectedItem (not scrolling)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a Windows 8 Metro app created in XAML, C# from the template. I need to navigate to the SplitPage and have an article selected. By default, the first article is selected (in the ListView and content shown on the right).

I need to force the SplitPage to select and show the n-th article. When I use this.itemsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToPosition(n) the desired item in the ListView is selected and data shown, but the ListBox does not scroll to this n-th item.

I tried setting the ListView's SelectedItem, SelectedIndex but nothing works. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/3063408d-6a13-4792-bd8f-abd58321455b

Comment: @Jonas I totally agree but it seems to be the only way for now

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method ScrollIntoView(object item) after the ListView is loaded to scroll to the currently selected item.  Make sure the control is loaded before you try to make the call.

```
private void itemListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    itemListView.ScrollIntoView(itemListView.SelectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myListView.ScrollIntoView(myListView.SelectedItem, ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Leading);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work like this:

```
        listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.SelectedItem);
        listView.UpdateLayout();
```